# Karate DataType changing in dynamic request

Tags: request, karate

i have a large json request with nested arrays. one of the field in array is expecting a number . i want to pass this value at run time . the issue is am facing is , the value (xyz=10) i am passing is getting converted into a string.
How to handle this issue?

Sample feature:

feature: dynamic json
Background:

```
* def req1 = 
"""
    {
      "system":
      {
        "appVersion": "xxx",
        "clientIP": "x.y.z.a",
        "isPayloadEncrypted": true,
        "encryptionKey": ""
      },
      "payload":
      {
        "selectedProducts": [
          {
           "prodCode": "abc",
            "paymentMode": "Y",
        "selectedOpt": null,
        "selectedESOpt": null,
        "selectedComponents": [
          {
            "compoCode": "abc",
            "premium": 0,
            'term': <xyz>,
            'premiumTerm': <xyz>,
            "sumAssured": 100000,
          },
          {
            "compoCode": "abc2",
            "premium": 0,
            'term': <xyz>,
            'premiumTerm': <xyz>,
            "sumAssured": 100000,
          },

        ]
      }
    ]

  }
}
```

"""

scenario: validate term
  * replace req1.xyz = 10
  Given url baseURL 
  And path 'anyPath'
  And request req1
  When method post
  Then status 200

Somehow, when request is getting generated it has  :
    "term": "10",
    "premiumTerm': "10",

while, it should be 
    "term": 10,
    "premiumTerm': 10,

error in log:

```
[Fatal Error] :6:3: The element type "meta" must be terminated by the matching end-tag "</meta>".
16:44:43.449 [main] WARN  com.intuit.karate - xml parsing failed, response data type set to string: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 6;
 columnNumber: 3; The element type "meta" must be terminated by the matching end-tag "</meta>".
16:44:43.449 [main] ERROR com.intuit.karate - status code was: 500, expected: 200, response time: 220, url: https://sqs-pacs-poeonline-qa.ocpapps
-dev.pru.intranet.asia/api/compute, response: <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Error</title>
</head>
<body>
<pre>TypeError: Cannot read property &#39;transactionId&#39; of undefined<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at app.use (/usr/app/src/app.js:23:42)<br> &nbsp; &nbs
p;at Layer.handle_error (/usr/app/src/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:71:5)<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at trim_prefix (/usr/app/src/node_modules/e
xpress/lib/router/index.js:315:13)<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at /usr/app/src/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:284:7<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at Function.p
rocess_params (/usr/app/src/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:335:12)<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at next (/usr/app/src/node_modules/express/lib/rout
er/index.js:275:10)<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at /usr/app/src/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:635:15<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at next (/usr/app/src/node_
modules/express/lib/router/index.js:260:14)<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at Layer.handle_error (/usr/app/src/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:67:12)<
br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at trim_prefix (/usr/app/src/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:315:13)</pre>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: error received:

Comment: 'Replace' keyword is changing it to a string. What to do if the requirement is to have the variable value changed to a number?

Answer (score 0):

You really should read the documentation a little more carefully. For [`replace`](https://github.com/intuit/karate#replace):

> Since replace auto-converts the result to a string, make sure you perform type conversion back to JSON (or XML) if applicable

And there is a whole section on [type conversion](https://github.com/intuit/karate#type-conversion).

But anyway, I think the solution best for this situation is [embedded-expressions](https://github.com/intuit/karate#embedded-expressions):

```
* def xyz = 10
* def req1 = 
"""
    {
      "system":
      {
        "appVersion": "xxx",
        "clientIP": "x.y.z.a",
        "isPayloadEncrypted": true,
        "encryptionKey": ""
      },
      "payload":
      {
        "selectedProducts": [
          {
           "prodCode": "abc",
            "paymentMode": "Y",
        "selectedOpt": null,
        "selectedESOpt": null,
        "selectedComponents": [
          {
            "compoCode": "abc",
            "premium": 0,
            'term': '#(xyz)',
            'premiumTerm': '#(xyz)',
            "sumAssured": 100000,
          },
          {
            "compoCode": "abc2",
            "premium": 0,
            'term': '#(xyz)',
            'premiumTerm': '#(xyz)',
            "sumAssured": 100000,
          },

        ]
      }
    ]

  }
}
"""
```